# How to make header for my web page [HTML5 , CSS3]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a header for my website and I want it to look like this.
[The header I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IxmO.png)

but I'm not sure what is the best way to make the logo look like that.

I've tried this,

```css
.logo {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -18px;
}

#circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
}

#rect {
  width: 120px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div id="circle"></div>
  <div id="rect"></div>
  <img src="img/MU-logo.png" alt="Madridismo" class="logo">

  <nav>
    <ul class="nav_links">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Games</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="clock"></div>

</header>
```

But I am still looking for the right way to do it. and thanks

Comment: Seems ok to me. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I used a circle behind the logo and rectangle on top of it to hide it's shadow, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same look.

Comment: the log0 is larger then the menubar. it uses border radius to round the bottom to a half circle and is proberly used with a z-index to actually be displayed above the menubar (layer-wise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. You will need to add the correct font and colors.

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav_links">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Games</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 
  <div class="center-circle">
     <img src="img/MU-logo.png" alt="Madridismo" class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="clock" id="clock"></div>

</header>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #999;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background: #fff;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49))
}

nav .nav_links {
  height: 4em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
/*   width: 15%; */
  list-style: none;
/*   margin-left: 1em; */
}

nav .nav_links li a{
  margin-left: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: pink;
}

header .logo {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -18px;
}

header .center-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -1px;
}

header .clock {
  height: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: darkblue;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```
// Automatic Clock
setInterval(getTime, 1000);

function getTime() {
  const date = new Date();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  // const seconds = date.getSeconds()
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = `${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;
  // if you want seconds to show: add ${seconds}
}
```

https://codepen.io/NathanielD/pen/YzWqdvV

Answer (score 1):

If you want your answer in html and css
Here

I used `flex` property on your `.nav_links` class and just make another class name `.time` for you 8:34 time and set it to `position:absolute` and `right:5%`. Let me know if it works for you or not.

```css
.logo {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -18px;
}
.nav_links {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
.time {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
}
li {
    color: rgb(255, 177, 190);
    font-size: 15px;
} 
.nav_links a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 177, 190);
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
}
#circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
}

#rect {
  width: 120px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<header>

        <div id="circle"></div>
        <div id="rect"></div>
        <img src="img/MU-logo.png" alt="Madridismo" class="logo">
      
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Games</a></li>
            <li class="time">8:34 AM</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      
        <div id="clock"></div>
      
      </header>
```